ERC-20 Congestion fee-
https://www.setf-coinbass.com/h5/#/pages/kefu/index - This exchange is charging me usd 30,000 fee for ERC-20 Congestion fee and also they did not complete my transaction of 150k transfer from my wallet on 4-25-24, now they wont let me transfer any money from my wallet unless I pay $30,000 transaction fee. However I have enough money in My wallet to cover this transaction fee, but they wont deduct it from my wallet, instead they want me to make external transfer to them. Which I can see a total scam. Any suggestions for recovering my invested money from these maggots.
